# How to return 2 cells using VLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to fill the last two columns according to a mapping table, using a `VLOOKUP`.

However I don't see the last column with Id as expected.

Why?[image]

`=VLOOKUP(C10:C,I28:K, {2,3}, FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

I had to add "ArrayFormula"

Is there any way to read which formula requires the `Arrayformula" to expand?

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(C10,I28:K28, {2,3}, FALSE))`